# Solve an ODE $y'' + y = \delta(t-\pi)\cos(t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I have to solve the differential equation using Laplace and find a solution on $[0,\infty)$. the equation is:
\begin{equation} y''(t) + y(t) = \delta(t-\pi)\cos(t)
\end{equation}
With the initial conditions: $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$.

I've tried to solve this by considering the right-handside to be a convolution. I get:
\begin{equation}
Y(s)(s^2+1) = \mathcal{L}[\delta_\pi * \cos(t)] + 1
\end{equation}
Now, I evaluate the convolution as:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}[\delta_\pi * \cos(t)] = \mathcal{L}[\delta\pi]\mathcal{L}[\cos(t)] = e^{-{\pi s}}*\frac{s}{s^2+1} 
\end{equation}
This gives me:
\begin{equation}
Y(s) = \frac{se^{-\pi s}}{(s^2+1)^2} + \frac{1}{s^2+1}
\end{equation}

From here, I've tried partial fraction decomposition but the first term is in its simplest form. I don't know how to continue from this point.

NB:
My teacher did a one-liner and solved it like this:
$\mathcal{L}(y''+y) = (s^2+1)\mathcal{L}[y]-1 = \mathcal{L}[\delta_\pi \cos(t)]$ "which can be rewritten" $\mathcal{L}[y] = \mathcal{L}(\sin(t)+\delta_\pi \cos(t)*\sin(t)$ --(I have no clue what happened after "which can be rewritten")
Thanks!

Comment: First, you should be using the simplification $\delta(t-a)f(t) = f(a)\delta(t-a)$. That way you only have a delta on the RHS.

Comment: The first term is the product of $\frac{s}{(s^2+1)^2}$ with $e^{-\pi s}$. Perhaps you can take the inverse Laplace transform of each of those and then convolve them?

Comment: Ninad - this works! Thank you very much!
Haydn - taking the LT of $\frac{s}{(s^2+1)^2}$ is very hard...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the s-domain expression $Y(s)$ is wrong (provided by @zeeko see above).

Therefore i would like to provide the correct solution.
The laplace transform of the ODE is

$$s^2 Y(s)-s y(0)+Y(s)+e^{-\pi  s}-y'(0)=0$$

This results in s-domain $Y(s)$

$$Y(s)\to \frac{e^{-\pi  s} \left(e^{\pi  s} y'(0)+e^{\pi  s} s y(0)-1\right)}{s^2+1}=\frac{y'(0)}{s^2+1}+\frac{s y(0)}{s^2+1}+\frac{e^{-\pi  s}}{s^2+1}$$

By inverse Laplace transform we obtain

$$y(t) \to\sin (t) \left(\theta (t-\pi )+y'(0)\right)+y(0) \cos (t)$$

Substituting the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$ we finally get

$$y(t) \to\sin (t) \left(\theta (t-\pi )+1\right)$$

or as a piecewise function

$$y(t) \to
\begin{cases}
\sin(t), & 0 \le t < \pi \\
2\sin(t), & t \ge \pi \\
\end{cases}$$

with $\theta(t)$ as the Heaviside Theta step function.